# Pseudo-element after freezes the page

Tags: css

I have an old project JSP page with the following CSS block which formats the main form div

```
 .container {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
        position:absolute;
        width: 400px;
        min-height: 300px;  
        height: auto;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -250px);
    }
```

requirement is such that I need to get a border around this form and in between some text so I used Pseudo-element **after** with following css block

```
.container:after {
  position: fixed;
  content : '\00a0  \00a0 \00a0 Login to external function';
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-top:15px;
  top: -40px;
  left: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  bottom: -25px;
  border: black 2px solid;
  border-spacing: 10px  
  }
```

I got the required output, but the form is freezing now, and I cannot click anything. Can you please help me know what I did wrong?

Comment: If by freeze, you mean that the form is visible but not clickable, you might want to check the z-index of ::after

Comment: thanks @nimsrules it worked with  z-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-elements are treated as **descendants** of their associated element. That means by default they sit above their parent in the stacking order. Even though in this case the pseudo-element is transparent, it is still blocking the `.container` below, preventing you from clicking it.

To fix it, you can place the pseudo-element behind its parent (.container) by giving it a negative [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value.